# Question about this recursive program, and how return works

Tags: c, function, recursion

In the function `prod()`, how does the program ever get past the `return 1;`, and where is it returning to?

When the program prints "test 1 at the beginning", the value of number is 1, the if statement is true, so it hits the `return 1`, and shouldn't it terminate there?

Does return not terminate the function?

I understand how the first 4 lines of output work, but I don't know how the code ever reaches the rest of the output. Any help is appreciated and this is just for practice for a future test.

Code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int prod(int number);

int
main(void)
{
    int x = 4;

    printf("The result of this function call is %d.\n", prod(x));
    return 0;
}

int
prod(int number)
{
    int p;

    printf("test %d at the beginning\n", number);
    if (number == 1)
        return 1;
    p = (number + 1) * prod(number - 1);
    printf("test %d at the end\n", number);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: `prod` does not *always* execute `return 1;`.

Comment: right, because number is not always equal to 1. but when num is finally equal to 1, the if statement is true, and it will return 1, and that closes the endless loop of recursion? but if it closes, how does the program even reach the last print statements? my question should have been rephrased, where does return 1 send 1 to?

Comment: The call stack something like `main->prod(4)->prod(3)->prod(2)->prod(1)`. At that point the last `prod(1)` returns and now the call stack becomes  `main->prod(4)->prod(3)->prod(2)` and so on until it gets back to `main`.

Comment: _Side note:_ Just curious. What is `prod` trying to do? The usual for a recursive would be: `p = number * prod(number - 1);` [vs `(number + 1)`]. **If** you're trying to compute `x!` (i.e. x factorial), then you really _do_ want `number * prod(number - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You call `prod(4)` from main. Within prod, you get past the first return since the conditional `(4 == 1)` is not true (therefore the return statement never gets executed).  Then you arrive at `p = (4 + 1) * prod(3)`. `prod(3)` does something similar: `p = (3 + 1) * prod(2)`. `prod(2)` sets `p = (2 + 1) * prod(1)` . Now in `prod(1)`, we hit the conditional `(1 == 1)` and this is flagged as true, so we enter into its code block, which simply is `return 1`. In a recursive function such as this, the function that returns, or does not recursively call itself is known as the bottom of the recursive stack (or a leaf in some cases). A return statement loads the context that called (the caller) the currently running function (the callee). In our case, the caller is `prod(2)`. Thus, `prod(2)`'s `p` is set to `(2+1) * 1` = 3, where 1 is the value just returned. `prod(2)` then executes the printf and returns its `p` (which is 3). This is returned to the function that called `prod(2)`, or `prod(3)`. `prod(3)`'s `p` then is `p = (3 + 1) * 3` (= `prod(2)` return value) = 12. Thus, `prod(3)` returns 12 back to `prod(4)` which is our top level of the recursive stack. `prod(4)` returns `p = (4 + 1) * 12` (= `prod(3)` return value) = 60. This is returned to main in the context of `printf`.